# Setting video stream metadata using Ffmpeg

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm using the JavaCV [FFmpegFrameRecorder](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameRecorder.java) class to encode Android's camera preview frames into a video.

The goal would be to replicate the result of the following command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate="90" output.mp4
```

I modified the `startUnsafe()` method as follows, but it failed to generate the desired output:

```
if ((video_st = avformat_new_stream(oc, video_codec)) != null) {
        video_c = video_st.codec();
        video_c.codec_id(oformat.video_codec());
        video_c.codec_type(AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
        ...
        AVDictionary avDictionary = new AVDictionary(null);
        av_dict_set(avDictionary, "rotate", "90", 0);
        video_st.metadata(avDictionaty);
        ...
}
...
avformat_write_header(oc, (PointerPointer) null);
```

This still encodes the video correctly, but the added metadata never appears on ffprobe. If it helps, the video encoding is h264.

By the way, here's the ffprobe output:

```
ffprobe version 2.3.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 22 2015 18:22:57 with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-libquvi --enable-libx265
  libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libavresample   1.  3.  0 /  1.  3.  0
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'abcd.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
  Duration: 00:00:19.48, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 572 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 573 kb/s, 5.71 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Any suggestions on why is it failing? Thanks.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024192/how-to-set-header-metadata-to-encoded-video

Answer (score 4):

It seems this question generated a lot of interest so I'm adding some more info. Following this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/132) Samuel from JavaCV [committed](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/commit/70db4a5835e376d5e8b70c26b9668332054b4696) some changes to allow easier access to metadata settings.

Setting metadata can be achieved through the following code snippet:

```
AVDictionary metadata = new AVDictionary(null);
for (Entry<String, String> e : videoMetadata.entrySet()) {
    av_dict_set(metadata, e.getKey(), e.getValue(), 0);
}
video_st.metadata(metadata);
```

You can enable it right now by doing `mvn install -Pffmpeg` or wait until the next JavacV release, which should be 0.12.

PS: As you can see, this is pretty similar to what I presented in my question, so I'm not sure why it didn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The `FFmpegFrameRecorder` [class](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameRecorder.java) you are using uses an `AVFormatContext` [class](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/blob/master/ffmpeg/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacpp/avformat.java). Around line 2579 you can see from the method signatures, that the `AVFormatContext` class uses native code to implement both

- `public native AVDictionary metadata()` method
- `public native AVFormatContext metadata(AVDictionary metadata)` method.

The answer to the link you provided says they used the `metadata` property of the `AVFormatContext` directly - something like the first method I think. But Line 649 of `FFmpegFrameRecorder` uses the second method - I suspect. i.e.:

```
AVDictionary metadata = new AVDictionary(null);
... code to fill up dictionary ...
...

avformat_write_header(oc.metadata(metadata), options);
```

Unfortunately I can't try this at the moment, but I wonder if you could do something like this:

```
AVDictionary metadata = co.metadata();
... code to fill up dictionary ...

//I would assume at this point that oc has the metadata so
avformat_write_header(oc, (PointerPointer) null);
//if not then maybe
// avformat_write_header(oc.metadata(metadata), options);
```

The signature shows it is public, so I don't see why you can't get the metadata dictionary from the `AVFormatContext` directly. I'm not sure how the `avformat_write_header` method works, so I suggested two things above.

**Note**: I have **not** used this library before. I tried, unsuccessfully to use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) in the past for some basic encoding.