# Metadata is not showing ffmpeg C++

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg, window

I am muxing h264 encoded video data and PCM g711 encoded audio data into a `.mov` media container. I am trying to write metadata on header but the metadata is not showing when I go to file->right click->properties->details on windows and likewise in Ubuntu. This is my code -

```
// Instead of creating new AVDictionary object, I also tried following way
// stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024192/how-to-set-header-metadata-to-encoded-video 
// but no luck
AVDictionary* pMetaData = m_pFormatCtx->metadata;
av_dict_set(&pMetaData, "title", "Cloud Recording", 0);
av_dict_set(&pMetaData, "artist", "Foobar", 0);
av_dict_set(&pMetaData, "copyright", "Foobar", 0);
av_dict_set(&pMetaData, "filename", m_sFilename.c_str(), 0);
time_t now = time(0);
struct tm tStruct = *localtime(&now);
char date[100];
strftime(date, sizeof(date), "%c", &tStruct); // i.e. Thu Aug 23 14:55:02 2001
av_dict_set(&pMetaData, "date", date, 0);
av_dict_set(&pMetaData, "creation_time", date, 0);
av_dict_set(&pMetaData, "comment", "This video has been created using Eyeball MSDK", 0);

// ....................
// .................

/* write the stream header, if any */
int ret = avformat_write_header(m_pFormatCtx, &pMetaData);
```

I also tried to see if the file contains any metadata using `mediainfo` and `exiftools` in linux. Also I tried `ffmpeg -i output.mov` but no metadata is shown.

Whats the problem? Is the `flags` value `0` in `av_dict_set` okay? DO I need to set different flags for different platform (windows/linux) ?

I saw [this link](http://jonhall.info/how_to/create_id3_tags_using_ffmpeg) and it stated that for windows, I have to use `id3v2_version 3` and `-write_id3v1 1` to make metadata working. If so, how can I do this in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have something similar to your code, but I'm adding the `AVDictionary` to my `AVFormatContext` [metadata](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/structAVFormatContext.html#a3019a56080ed2e3297ff25bc2ff88adf) parameter and it works for me that way. Here's a snippet based on your code.

```
AVDictionary *pMetaData = NULL;
av_dict_set(&pMetaData, "title", "Cloud Recording", 0);
m_pFormatCtx->metadata = pMetaData;
avformat_write_header(m_pFormatCtx, NULL);
```

Comment: Just a note for any other confused user, there are only certain pieces of metadata that can be used with a given format. For instance av_dict_set(&pMetaData, "my_custom_metatype", "my_custom_metadata", 0); is likely to fail silently.